# Adding a columnname and rowname into list elements in R

Tags: r, list, merge

I am a growing R user and need help with a wall that I've hit.

I am having a hard time finding a solution for my situation.

> I have to nested lists which I need to join together

```
 ListA:
 [abc]:
 [1] 0 1 1 2
 [2] 2 0 4 5
 [3] 3 5 0 6
 [4] 2 3 1 0

 [def]
 [1] 0 4 2
 [2] 2 0 1
 [3] 1 1 0

 List B:
 [abc]:
 [1] 111 112 113 114

 [def]:
 [1] 222 223 224
```

these 2 lists does span 82 tables each, same format, same element. Which means I need a scable code, that does not manually target each list or element.

> I want to take the ListB, and add it as first column and first row of ListA >either as column/row names or just in the data itself like these:

```
 ListC:
 [abc]:
      111 112 113 114
 [111]  0   1   1   2
 [112]  2   0   4   5
 [113]  3   5   0   6
 [114]  2   3   1   0

 [def]:
      222 223 224
 [222]  0   4   2
 [223]  2   0   1
 [224]  1   1   0
```

I have tried various ways of

```
 mapply(cbind, ListB,ListA, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

with

```
 mapply(rbind, Listb,ListA, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)
```

I have also tried to

```
 lapply(ListA, function(x){
    names(x) <- ListB
    df
    })
```

also

```
 Map(setNames, ListA, names(ListB))
```

And various random iterations of these codes.

Sometimes I can get a column names to work, but won't work for row names (visa versa), since the "total vector size" is not the same.

What am I missing? from separating the 82 lists into dataframes and manually handling it one by one,(which is not dynamic at all) I am completely stumped!

Please let me know what I need to do in order to make this work

Answer (score 1):

Consider extending your function call with multiple lines. Then call `Map` with the user-defined method.

```
name_items <- function(elem, nm) {
   colnames(elem) <- nm
   rownames(elem) <- nm

   return(elem)
}

newListA <- Map(name_items, ListA, ListB)
newListA <- mapply(name_items, ListA, ListB, SIMPLIFY=FALSE)   #  EQUIVALENT CALL
```

Comment: Or, a harder to read way: `Map(\`dimnames<-\`, listA, lapply(listB, function(x) list(x,x)))`

Answer (score 1):

It would help to include code to generate sample data. Anyway, I used `purrr` to do this.

```r
library(purrr)

listA <- list(abc = matrix(c(0,2,3,2,1,0,5,3,1,4,0,1,2,5,6,0),4,4), def = matrix(c(0,2,1,4,0,1,2,1,0),3,3))
listA
#> $abc
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
#> [1,]    0    1    1    2
#> [2,]    2    0    4    5
#> [3,]    3    5    0    6
#> [4,]    2    3    1    0
#> 
#> $def
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    0    4    2
#> [2,]    2    0    1
#> [3,]    1    1    0

listB <- list(abc = c(111,112,113,114), def = c(222,223,224))
listB
#> $abc
#> [1] 111 112 113 114
#> 
#> $def
#> [1] 222 223 224

finalList <- map2(.x = listA, .y = listB, .f = function(.x, .y){
  rownames(.x) <- .y
  colnames(.x) <- .y
  return(.x)
})

finalList
#> $abc
#>     111 112 113 114
#> 111   0   1   1   2
#> 112   2   0   4   5
#> 113   3   5   0   6
#> 114   2   3   1   0
#> 
#> $def
#>     222 223 224
#> 222   0   4   2
#> 223   2   0   1
#> 224   1   1   0
```

This should in theory also work if your data are data.frames instead of matrices